# The Heaviside step function at zero and the integral of the Dirac delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta, step-function

Just for fun I was reading about the Heaviside step function [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). The definition in terms of the Dirac delta function makes sense:

$$
H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \delta(s)\ ds
$$

$\delta(s) = 0$ for all $s \in [-\infty, 0)$. For other values of $s$, $\delta(s) \not= 0$ only at one point, so the integral (area) equals the value at that point, $1$.

However, later on in the article it reads (emphasis mine):

> Since $H$ is usually used in integration, and **the value of a function at a single point does not affect its integral**, it rarely matters what particular value is chosen of $H(0)$.

If the value at a single point does not affect the integral for $H$, why does it for $\delta$? In other words, why does the following equation not hold, assuming the above quote?

$$
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(s)\ ds = 0
$$

I must be misunderstanding something about either integrals or the Dirac delta function.

Comment: What you are misunderstanding is about the Dirac delta "function." It is not a "function" in the classic sense of $f:X\to Y$ which assigns to each element in $X$ an element $f(x)$ in $Y$. It is instead a "distribution" which is a generalization of the notion of a function.

Answer (score 2):

Formally, the dirac delta is not a function in the same sense as the heaviside function.

Rather, it is a [distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to think of the dirac delta function is:
$$\delta_n(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x<0 \\
n & 0<x<\frac1n \\
0 & x>\frac1n
\end{cases}$$
$$\delta(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\delta_n(x)$$
Now try and integrate $\delta_n(x)$ first then take the limit:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta_n(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^0\delta_n(x)dx+\int_0^{\frac1n}\delta_n(x)dx+\int_{\frac1n}^\infty\delta_n(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^00.dx+\int_0^{\frac1n}ndx+\int_{\frac1n}^\infty0.dx$$
$$=n\left[x\right]_0^{1/n}=1$$
and now:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta_n(x)dx=1$$

Comment: Why is that "the best way"?

Comment: It explains why the integral over the reals is 1 despite the function not being bounded

Comment: There are other ways to prove it ...

Comment: Ok let's see then